# How to retrieve data from a jsp page to my store using Sencha Touch 2

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, sencha-touch

I would like an example of this. Please give me a detailed example.

Comment: Take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to use SO. You are asking SO to write the code for you. Usually you show the code you are working on and together we look for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the results in a Store, first create your model like this:

```
Ext.define('app.model.Example', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            fields: ['data'],
        }
});
```

Next, create your Store:

```
Ext.define('app.store.Examples', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'app.model.Example',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
    },
});
```

An example of JSONP request is easy to find in Sencha Touch 2 Kitchensink Demo. Here I added some code to add the results to your store:

```
                Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                    url: 'http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx',
                    callbackKey: 'callback',
                    params: {
                        key: '23f6a0ab24185952101705',
                        q: '94301', // Palo Alto
                        format: 'json',
                        num_of_days: 5
                    },

                    callback: function(success, result) {
                        var store = Ext.getStore('Examples');
                        var weather = result.data.weather;

                        if (weather) {
                            store.add({data: weather});
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('There was an error retrieving the weather.');
                        }

                        panel.getParent().unmask();
                    }
                });
```

Hope it helps ... Let me know if there are any errors.